# How to check if python is already installed?

Tags: 20.04

When I tried `whereis python` it returns me following list:

`python: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8`

Does that mean python is already installed in my machine ?

But when I try to `yarn install` in my project, it returns me following error:

```
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.3.0 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```

Comment: You could simply install this package to make python2.7 life easier `sudo apt install python-is-python2`  Does not interfere with python3 whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

Your computer has `python3.8` installed. To quickly check whether `python2` is installed, run the command `python2 --version`, and your computer will most likely show `command not found`, because it is most likely not installed in your system.

Use the command `sudo apt install python2` to install `python2`.

Also, in the recent versions of Ubuntu, `python2` has to be called with the command `python2`, not just `python`.

**Warning:** Do not try to remove `python3`, or change the default Python version to 2. `python3.8` is preinstalled in your version of Ubuntu, and major components of Ubuntu depend on it. You can safely have both `python2` and `python3` installed.

Comment: Yeah I tried removing python3 & end up requiring ubuntu to reinstall. That's why I post this question

Answer (score 1):

You can check using `python2 --version` for python2 and `python3 --version` for python3. You can also use `which python` to verify which python will be used when called. Apparently it is installed in your machine, but yarn could not find it.

Comment: python 3.8.5 is installed.

Comment: apparently it is trying to find `python2`

Comment: How can I fix it ?

Comment: install python2

Comment: So i need to remove python3 ? or is there any way yarn to use python 2 ?

Comment: you can have both installed in your pc. Apparently yarn will chose of them depending on the application you want to install